# Mule requester is consuming all the messages from JMS queue

Tags: jms, mule, mule-studio

I am facing a minor issue using Mule requester .. 
I have the following Mule flow :-

```
 <!-- This flow sends payload to ActiveMQ -->
 <flow name="SendPayloadToActiveMQ" doc:name="mulerequesterdemoFlow1">
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8088/requester" doc:name="HTTP"/>
 <set-payload value="My Payload" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
 <jms:outbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" queue="input" connector-ref="Active_MQ"/>
 </flow>

 <!-- This flow consumes 3 payload from ActiveMQ -->
<flow name="CountRequester" doc:name="CountRequester">
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" path="request3messages"/>
 <mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="jms://input" doc:name="Mule Requester" count="3"/>
 <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Payload: #[payload]"/>
    </flow>
```

Now as you can see the first flow **SendPayloadToActiveMQ** will send payload to the JMS queue **input** queue  and the second flow **CountRequester** will consume only 3 messages from JMS **input** queue .. 
 But now the issue is if there are 6 messages in the **input** queue, then the second flow is consuming all the 6 messages from the queue and the queue is left blank .. 
I can even see it in the logger that all the six messages are consumed Payload: org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
`Payload: [My Payload, My Payload, My Payload, My Payload, My Payload, My Payload]`
But it was suppose to consume only 3 messages as I configured
 `<mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="jms://input" doc:name="Mule Requester" count="3"/>`
that was supposed to consume only 3 messages ....
Please help .. am I doing any thing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be a bug in the logic to stop the iteration: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester/commit/4ad1fd74b2dc76e1231c246623909f5e4fe4f145#diff-2

So what version of the requester module are you using?

**EDIT**: It appears there's another bug that prevents `request-collection` to honour the requested `count`: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester/issues/9

To go around the issue you can either:

- Fix the bug yourself (more the variable initialization above the while loop) and use your own snapshot of the module.
- Implement the same logic in a small Groovy component. You could simply return a `java.util.List` of payloads instead of a `MuleMessageCollection`.