# mule requester collection is not returning file name in it's properties

Tags: mule, mule-component

When i am using `mulerequester:request` to fetch file from SFTP endpoint,filename comes under inbound property `originalFileName` .But when i tried to use `mule-requester:request-collection` filename did not come under inbound property `originalFilename`.

Can you guys help me out in fetching file names using `mule-requester:request-collection`?

Comment: There were few bugs with `mule-requester:request-collection` ,  
you can find it here :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834912/mule-requester-is-consuming-all-the-messages-from-jms-queue  ...  May be a bug   
Make sure you haven't came across any such bugs with  `mule-requester:request-collection`

Comment: Hi Anibaran, I have seen all the bugs in this list but it seems this issue does not corresponds to any bug.

Comment: may be or may be not a bug I am not sure .. but the mule mulerequester had issues with mule-requester:request-collection earlier .. make sure you haven't came across a new bug

Comment: one more question we will iterate over message or paylod from mulerequester:request-collection?

Comment: payload is a part of message which contains the actual data ... message has other different parts like inbound properties, outbound properties etc which are like headers and payload is like the actual data you are sending

Comment: I was going through the code mule-requester .There i found that mulerequester:request-collection will return collection of mule messages.So i was confused that all the files info will be stored in payload or header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, `mule-requester:request-collection` returns a `MuleMessageCollection` so the `originalFilename` inbound property (and all others) should be in each `MuleMessage` of that collection. 
I'm pretty sure you can handle that collection with a [`foreach`](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Foreach) scope.
HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .Actually i was using foreach collection .Hence it was not coming as an inbound property.Now i am using Foreach and i am getting it.

Comment: I was thinking for a long how to get the inbound properties and for each helped thanks

Answer (score 0):

There were few bugs with `mule-requester:request-collection` ,
you can find it here :-[Mule requester is consuming all the messages from JMS queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834912/mule-requester-is-consuming-all-the-messages-from-jms-queue)  ...  May be a bug
Make sure you haven't came across any such bugs with  `mule-requester:request-collection`

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with losing the filename too. My initial flow as as follows

```
  <file:connector name="FormDefinitonFileConnector" autoDelete="true" streaming="false"
validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" fileAge="50" />
<flow name="migrateFromFilePath">
<mulerequester:request-collection resource="file:///C:/DEV" doc:name="Request a files from a location" />
<logger message="Message before foreach: #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload]">
  <logger message="originalFilename: #[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]-#[server.dateTime]"
    level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
  <logger message="Message after foreach: #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
  <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:/DEV/processed" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
</foreach>
```

What I believe is happening, is the foreach is configured to loop through the array of the payload

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload]">
```

Where the contents of each payload is not a Mule message, but a collection of files that we have loaded.

```
INFO  2017-05-19 11:36:18,520 [[cf_migrator].api-
httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
Message before foreach: 
org.mule.DefaultMessageCollection
{
id=fe1f27d0-3c7e-11e7-856a-54391dd0f207
payload=java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList
correlationId=<not set>    
correlationGroup=-1
correlationSeq=-1
encoding=UTF-8
exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
    INVOCATION scoped properties:
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_AcceptedHeaders=*/*
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_apikitRouterRequest=yes
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_contractMimeTypes=[]
    INBOUND scoped properties:
    OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    SESSION scoped properties:
    }
INFO  2017-05-19 11:36:18,569 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Setting originalFilename: null-2017-05-19T11:36:18.563+01:00
INFO  2017-05-19 11:36:18,570 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Message after foreach: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=fe20d580-3c7e-11e7-856a-54391dd0f207
  payload=[B
  correlationId=fe1f27d0-3c7e-11e7-856a-54391dd0f207
  correlationGroup=2
  correlationSeq=1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_AcceptedHeaders=*/*
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_apikitRouterRequest=yes
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_contractMimeTypes=[]
    counter=1
    rootMessage=<<<MuleMessage>>>
  INBOUND scoped properties:
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=2
    MULE_CORRELATION_ID=fe1f27d0-3c7e-11e7-856a-54391dd0f207
    MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=1
  SESSION scoped properties:
}
```

Thanks to this answer 
[Use a splitter to retain filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843366/using-mule-requester-and-ftp-loses-originalfilename)

Replacing the foreach with a splitter, generates a Mule message for each file that is processed

```
<file:connector name="FormDefinitonFileConnector" autoDelete="true" streaming="false"
validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" fileAge="50" />
<flow name="migrateFromFilePath">
    <mulerequester:request-collection resource="file:///C:/DEV" doc:name="Request a files from a location" />
    <logger message="Message before splitter: #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
      <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
      <logger message="Setting originalFilename: #[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]-#[server.dateTime]"
    level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
      <logger message="Message after splitter: #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
      <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:/DEV/processed" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
</flow>
```

Now we have a Mule message that contains the filename and the file contents as a payload

```
INFO  2017-05-19 11:50:07,240 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor:             
Message before splitter: 
org.mule.DefaultMessageCollection
{
  id=ec09b8b0-3c80-11e7-a8cf-54391dd0f207
  payload=java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_AcceptedHeaders=*/*
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_apikitRouterRequest=yes
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_contractMimeTypes=[]
  INBOUND scoped properties:
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
  SESSION scoped properties:
}
INFO  2017-05-19 11:50:07,286 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Setting originalFilename: collectionBetweenRowsFormDef.json-2017-05-19T11:50:07.281+01:00
INFO  2017-05-19 11:50:07,288 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Message after splitter: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=ec0f5e00-3c80-11e7-a8cf-54391dd0f207
  payload=[B
  correlationId=ec09b8b0-3c80-11e7-a8cf-54391dd0f207
  correlationGroup=2
  correlationSeq=1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_AcceptedHeaders=*/*
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_apikitRouterRequest=yes
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_contractMimeTypes=[]
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    directory=C:\DEV
    fileSize=14696
    originalDirectory=C:\DEV
    originalFilename=file1.json
    timestamp=1495120341439
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=2
    MULE_CORRELATION_ID=ec09b8b0-3c80-11e7-a8cf-54391dd0f207
    MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=1
  SESSION scoped properties:
}
INFO  2017-05-19 11:50:07,350 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'FormDefinitonFileConnector.dispatcher.1900990765'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2017-05-19 11:50:07,350 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'FormDefinitonFileConnector.dispatcher.1900990765'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2017-05-19 11:50:07,354 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: C:\DEV\processed\ec26b690-3c80-11e7-a8cf-54391dd0f207.dat
INFO  2017-05-19 11:50:07,357 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor:     Setting originalFilename: file1.json-2017-05-19T11:50:07.357+01:00
INFO  2017-05-19 11:50:07,357 [[cf_migrator].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor:     Message after splitter: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=ec0ffa40-3c80-11e7-a8cf-54391dd0f207
  payload=[B
  correlationId=ec09b8b0-3c80-11e7-a8cf-54391dd0f207
  correlationGroup=2
  correlationSeq=2
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_AcceptedHeaders=*/*
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_apikitRouterRequest=yes
    _ApikitResponseTransformer_contractMimeTypes=[]
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    directory=C:\DEV
    fileSize=54143
    originalDirectory=C:\DEV
    originalFilename=file2.json
    timestamp=1495124035101
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=2
    MULE_CORRELATION_ID=ec09b8b0-3c80-11e7-a8cf-54391dd0f207
    MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=2
  SESSION scoped properties:
}
```